# Does DBAL support SELECT FOR UPDATE update/delete lock on other database users?

Tags: mysql, locking, row, readonly, dbal

I'm using **DBAL** in my project because it is easier to convert the database statements in an already written project that I'm converting to **Symfony v2.8** and **MySQL** than going with full-on **Doctrine**, but now I need to implement "read-only row locks" to prevent data changes by other users while a pair of tightly coupled but separate **SELECT** statements are consecutively executed, and I'm thinking that I should use **Transactions** and **SELECT FOR UPDATE** statements.  However, I don't see that **DBAL** supports **SELECT FOR UPDATE** statements in it's documentation.  I do see that **Transactions** are supported, but as I understand it, these won't prevent other users from **UPDATE**-ing or **DELETE**-ing the data in the same data row that the SELECTs statements are using.

Specifically, the two **SELECT**s share data retrieved in one row by the first **SELECT** with a second **SELECT** that retrieve multiple rows from the same tables based on the first **SELECT**.  The two **SELECT**s are somewhat complex, and I don't know if I could combine them into a super-sized single **SELECT**, nor do I really want to as that would make the new **SELECT** harder to maintain in the future.

The problem is that other users could be updating the same values retrieved by the first **SELECT** and if this done between the the two **SELECT**s, it would break the second **SELECT** of the pair and either prevent the second from returning data or at least return the wrong data.

I believe that I need to use a **SELECT FOR UPDATE** to lock the row that it retrieve to temporarily prevent other users from performing their updates and deletes on the single row retrieved by the first **SELECT** of the pair, but since I'm not actually performing an update, but rather two **SELECT**s, how do I release the lock on the one row locked by the first **SELECT** without performing a 'fake' update, say by **UPDATE**-ING a column value with the same value it already had?

Thanks

Comment: MySQL's default isolation level is repeatable read. So when a `SELECT` happens, the next SELECT in the same transaction will return the same rows. Another transaction may have changed the result, but the original transaction maintains a consistent view.

Comment: danblack, thanks for your reply.  I don't understand your comment about MySQL's default isolation level.  Let me clarify what I'm trying to prevent: I don't think that the two SELECTs are the same transaction because their WHERE-Clauses aren't the same.  Both use the same tables, but the first SELECT's WHERE uses one tables' primary key equals a specific value to select the one row.  The second SELECT's WHERE uses data from the first SELECT to get many rows, but doesn't include the one row from the first SELECT.  This isn't the same transaction is it and other user's updates sneak in, right?

Comment: I re-read your answer, I think you're saying that all of the SELECTs included inside of a single transaction 'see' the same, unchanged, data from the tables used by both SELECT statements regardless of the any possible changes in these tables made by other users after the transaction starts executing.  So, I only need to explicitly create the transaction before doing the two SELECTs and end the transaction after they finish executing, and that I don't need worry about creating an explicit lock with a SELECT FOR UPDATE statement or releasing it, right -- right?

Comment: Another twist.  This all runs from PHP, and the first SELECT has to return a single row back to my PHP script so it can be used to create and execute the second SELECT.  How does MySQL know that the two SELECT are part of a single transaction?  Does the first SELECT having the LOCK IN SHARE MODE phrase do this?  How does MySQL know when the transaction is complete?  These SELECTs join multiple, but the same, tables, does the first SELECT lock the single row in all of the joined table?  Continued in the next comment...

Comment: Should I wrap the SELECTs with START TRANSACTION and END TRANSACTION?  I don't want to close the connection DB after running the SELECTs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the transaction you want repeatable results for:

[START TRANSACTION READ ONLY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/commit.html)

SELECT ...

{some processing}

SELECT {that covers the same rows}  [will return the same result]

COMMIT

note: `READ ONLY` is optional

Experiment by running two mysql client connections and observer the results. The other connection can modify or insert rows covering the first selects criteria and the first transaction won't observe them.

Comment: Thanks for making this much clearer.  Does the first SELECT still need the LOCK IN SHARED MODE phrase or since this is the default  the phase isn't needed?  Also, since there are only SELECTs in the transaction, why do you include a COMMIT statement?

Comment: `COMMIT` is needed to close the transaction.  `LOCK IN SHARE` can be used if you want other transactions from updating those rows. It isn't however required.

Comment: Thanks again, especially for the quick response.

Comment: Just so it's said more clearly, at least to me, the LOCK IN SHARE MODE phase of first the SELECT isn't required because the transaction uses with a cached, unchanged, version of the row of each table found/joined/returned in the first SELECT when the second SELECT runs in the transaction, therefore I don't really need the read-only lock, and other users can update the actual table rows without interfering with my two SELECTs.